# Array splitting with regex

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, hash

I have an array that holds only one string, it's hash's value:

```
%hash = ("key"=>["Value1 unit(1), Value2 unit(2), Value3 unit"])
```

How to split the `" unit"`-s from the value of the hash and save it to an array?

The new array should be like this:

```
@array=["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
```

I've tried this way:

```
@array=split(/\s\w\(\w\)\,/, $hash{key});
```

Comment: Why not split on comma, then use `map` to remove the `unit` suffix from each of them.

Comment: The problem is that the last `unit` doesn't have a comma after it, so it's not like the other separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on comma, then strip off the unit at the end.

```
map(s/\s.*$//, @array = split(/,\s*/, $hash{'key'}[0]));
```

Comment: what about if "unit"-s are random things like R(ohm), V(u) etch

Comment: The real key value just looks like this:::
`1567 I(u), 2070 I(m), 2.456e-2 V(m), 417  ---, 12 R(k),`

haven't added to the thread, thought can be done with regex

Comment: So you just want to remove everything after the space? That's easy.

Comment: i just want to push these values to an array ::: `1567,2080,2.456e-2,417,12`

Comment: I just fixed a the `split` to include the spaces after the comma as part of the delimiter. Now my answer works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my %hash = ("key"=>["1567 I(u), 2070 I(m), 2.456e-2 V(m), 417 ---, 12 R(k),"]);
my @array =  $hash{'key'}->[0] =~ /(\S+)\s+\S+,?/g;
print Dumper \@array;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1567',
          '2070',
          '2.456e-2',
          '417',
          '12'
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

And another option:

```
my %hash = ("key"=>["Value1 unit(1), Value2 unit(2), Value3 unit"]);

my $i;
my @array = grep { ++$i % 2 } split /,?\s/, $hash{key}->[0];

$, = "\n";
print @array;
```

Comment: could you please explane this `grep { ++$i % 2 }`

Comment: @Rocker [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) is basically a list filter operation, in this case we process the six elements returned by the split. `++$i % 2` uses [`modulus`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) to return either 1 (push element onto array) or 0 (skip element), effectively skipping each even element as `$i` increments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single relatively straightforward regex:

```
@array = $hash{'key'}[0] =~ m/\s*(\S+)\s+\S+,?/g;
```

The important thing to know is that with the `/g` flag, a regex matcher returns all the captured (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) groups from matching globally against the string.  This regex has one such group.

My assumptions are:

1. The "Value1", "Value2" parts are just chunks of non-whitespace
2. The "unit(1)", "unit(2)", parts are also just chunks of non-whitespace

If these aren't valid assumptions, you can replace the two `\S+` parts of the regex with something more specific that matches your data.

Comment: Oops, this is essentially the same solution as @Kenosis posted.  Somehow I missed that.